# Unable to know Output of this Multi threading Program

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi I am unable to find the reason why I am getting this output. First output I understood but second line I am unable to understand. I am new to threading and I googled but still in doubt. Can someone please explain?

Output is:

```
Inside ThreadEx
Inside ThreadEx
```

Here is my code:

```
class ThreadEx extends Thread {

    ThreadEx() {}

    ThreadEx(Runnable r)
    {
        super(r);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside ThreadEx");
    }
}

class RunnableEx implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Inside RunnableEx ");   
    }
}

public class Test4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ThreadEx().start();
        new ThreadEx(new RunnableEx()).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you override `run()` method in your `ThreadEx` class. If you use

```
new Thread(new RunnableEx()).start()
```

instead of

```
new ThreadEx(new RunnableEx()).start()
```

you'll see the expected output (I guess the expected output is `Inside ThreadEx Inside RunnableEx`)

Answer (score 1):

`Thread` class implements `Runnable` interface which has the method `run()` and the `Thread` class provides a default implementation for that method.

> ABOUT YOUR CODE-->

So the first line of main method is calling the default constructor of Class `ThreadEx` which extends `Thread` Class. It has one method `run()` which actually is a method of `Thread` superclass which you can override, so i think `@Override` is missing above the `run()` method. Ok until here.

So where you see

```
new ThreadEX().start();
```

you are doing the above plus you start this thread. You have implemented `run()` as mentioned  and it will print 'Inside ThreadX'.

> SECOND LINE OF MAIN METHOD-->

The next line of main method is calling the second constructor of class `ThreadEX` giving a `Runnable` object. As you see is providing `RunnableEX` which is a class implementing this interface. It overrides the `run()` method. So when you start the thread in this line

```
new ThreadEx(new RunnableEx()).start();
```

`Thread` it will print 'Inside RunnableEX'

> About Overriding

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Answer (score 0):

Your overwriting the Threads "run" method.
The original "run" method calls the "run" method of the Runnable (here: "r").
But you overwrote it, so it will only call your "System.out. ..."

The Original is

```
@Override
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

you replace it with

```
public void run()
{
    System.out.println("Inside ThreadEx");
}
```

so only the second one will be executed, no matter what your Runnable says.